# Call of Juarez stutters every time something loads

Tags: pc, performance, call-of-juarez

I'm still at the start of the game but one thing is annoying as hell: whenever I'm maneuvering around in the map and the game needs to load something (e.g. a sound or such a thing), there's a stutter or a short pause, so to say.
When I e.g. climb up to something, it's clear that the game suddenly pauses for the sound to load if it's the first time it needs to play it (at least, that's my impression). I've also seen this the first time the wolf came at me, right in the tutorial: a short stop and then the sound played.

What's also really annoying about this, is that it almost always breaks the tension, because I already can expect something to happen the next moment.

I'm on a W7Pro 64 with 12GB RAM, i980EE@3.3Ghz, with Intel 160GB SSD and a HD 5970, so I don't think it's my hardware that's insufficient. All my searching using Google and asking friends turned up nothing (as they usually expect problems based on the hardware not being up to par).

I also noticed some weird, albeit less annoying stops, when calling up the Objective or Log screens (I expect the game to pause in this case, so no problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing affinity as suggested by CJM made things just worse as long as less then four CPUs where selected. But it didn't improve anything at all.

I didn't bother with the disk performance tools, wouldn't believe I'm in trouble with the SSD as I know (and have measured in the past) my throughput is around 200MB reading.

I've no such hogging background processes, [I don't run antivirus](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/choosing-anti-anti-virus-software.html) (exactly because of this). Checked with `msconfig.exe`, all automatically started services looked normal and tools started on system startup looked good as well.

Finally I tried to play around with compatibility setting when I found a `CoJ_DX10.exe` in the game directory. It never occurred to me this file exists as typing `Juarez` in the W7 start menu only provides my on links which starts up `CoJ.exe` it seems.

After starting `CoJ_DX10.exe` and configuring my settings (everything maxed out at 1600x1200) and played again from the start -> there was no stutter at all anymore. Besides, it looks better still at 85 FPS ...

So simple I can't believe it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities I can think of. The game performs poorly on 64 bit systems, or the game performs poorly on multi-core systems. Some games which were optimised for two cores works poorly on quad (or more) core systems. Fallout 3 for example crashes on some quad core systems unless you edit a configuration file.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Never had any troubles so far, even with older games (way older then CoJ). F3 plays well on my system. Any concrete idea what I can do?

Comment: @mark: Nope. Sorry.

Comment: You can test this by modifying the processor affinity and by using application compatibility settings: 

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-processor-affinity-to-an-application-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Beyond application compatibility and processor affinity, you also need to consider background processes. Anti-virus apps are the old favourites, but any background application could potential be a problem. I suggest using msconfig.exe to temporarily cut out all but essential processes before playing the game.

It might not yield results, but you need to cross it off your list.

This stutters are often due to disk bottlenecks. You'd hope this wouldn't be the case with an SSD but you never know - you need to benchmark your disk system ([HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/)).

Post back with your observations and we might be able to dig deeper.

Q: Is it just CoJ that suffers in this way? I assume you are fully patched? If it is just CoJ, I'd log a call with the developers...